# How to execute a stunned zombie in Dying Light?

Tags: pc, dying-light

I'm assuming that when you hit a zombie and then see its skeleton (X-ray vision) it means it's stunned, but how do I then execute it?

There's no "hint" on the screen or anything to tell me what key to hit. There's nothing in the key binding settings about execution. I tried <kbd>E</kbd> (kick) and <kbd>LMB</kbd> (attack), but they do not work.

I'm playing on PC.

Comment: You should have the option to *Takedown* a zombie after you see the skeleton.  Try getting closer and aiming at its head?

Comment: Been trying that. Nothing. Only a hint telling me I can grapple it in a direction (`ALT + Arrow` if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: Grappling a zombie is a different perk than actually finishing one off. There's another perk that lets you execute a zombie that's down on the ground by stomping on it's head.

Comment: (Or maybe I'm confusing that with something else.)

Comment: Ok I think the problem is that I only got the perk that gives you 10% stun with a kick (tbh it's way less), and I can't execute anything because those are different perks. The confusing part is that in the kick-stun perk, it says "execute with `E`", which somehow implies that you can execute them after the stun (otherwise I don't really see how they are more easily killed while stunned as the perk suggests).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To execute a stunned zombie on the ground, you need the [Stomp](http://dyinglight.wikia.com/wiki/Stomp) skill.**

As far as I've experienced on the PC, when you see the x-ray skeleton, that part of the zombie is "stunned" or otherwise impaired. **The kick-stun skill alone does not enable you to execute zombies.**

From your comments the "execute with `E`" text refers to the act of [performing](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/execute) the kick, like you would execute a command or application on a PC; to *initiate* the kick.

The "more easily killed" part I believe refers to the fact that because they are stunned, you can just walk up to them and bash them until, er, dead.